# Connecting to Dynamics 365 CRM Multi Factor Authentication

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to connect to my Dynamics 365 CRM trial online version through C# and I'm stuck on the connection process.
The problem is about the LoginPrompt because I have set the 2FA and when I run the application, a pop-up shows me I have to write the credentials and authorize the login through my authenticator app. I would like to login without the program asking me to insert the credentials without removing 2FA.
If I set LoginPrompt to "Never", It doesn't work because "organizationService" variable become null

Here the code

```
string connectionString = @"AuthType=OAuth; Url=https://<orgName>.crm4.dynamics.com; 
Username=<username>; Password=<password>; SkipDiscovery=true; 
RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97; AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d; LoginPrompt=Auto";
CrmServiceClient crmServiceClient = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
IOrganizationService organizationService = crmServiceClient.OrganizationWebProxyClient ?? (IOrganizationService)crmServiceClient.OrganizationServiceProxy;
if (organizationService != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Connection established...");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect!!!");
```

Comment: create an azure app registration and use a clientid/clientsecret instead

Comment: Every person on the planet created an azure app? Because it's mandatory to have 2FA active

Comment: @Alex95 - if the purpose of the connection is for service to service (non-interactive) then yes, it should have an app created and use a cert or secret to access. If it's interactive then it can use the interactive browser-based login flow which pops up a browser dialog.  Hope that helps!